# How do I catch Exceptions 0xC00002B5 and 0xC000041D in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2017

in debug mode of my Win32 application with VS2017, I get unhandled exceptions 0xC00002B5 and 0xC000041D even though the debugger flag "break when this exception type is thrown" is not set.

Now I tried to catch these exceptions to no avail.

Does anybody know how to catch these exceptions?

TIA Michael

Things I tried:

```
        try
    {
        // do something that gives the exception
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
    }


    TRY
    {
        // do something that gives the exception
    }
    CATCH_ALL(exception)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
    }
    END_CATCH_ALL
```

EDIT: I found a little code snipped to produce the 0xC000041D exception:

```
            const double NULLNUM = 1e+12;
        double dOvrdVal = NULLNUM;
        long lVal = (long)dOvrdVal;
        lVal++;
```

Comment: These errors are Structured Exceptions not C++ exceptions: `0xC00002B5` is a floating point trap exception and `0xC000041D` is usually associated with a system callback.  You really need to fix these errors and not try and suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

At first try `catch(...)` to see it if catches or not.

If it does not(I guess it will not), you can try using `__try/__except` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/try-except-statement)). It will catch everything including memory access violation, but you will not be able to use C++ `try/catch` at same time.

Finally, normally exceptions that is thrown in Win32 debug mode is debug purpose only, showing some bugs to solve. For example, `CloseHandle()` throws it on invalid or closed handle. It is better idea find the reason these exceptions are thrown and solve these bugs in the code.

Comment: catch(...) didn't catch either. But __try works. Unfortunately, my problem is with a OnDraw routine so I cannot use __try. Even after a workaround (moving the code into a static function) I get another exception (something about "recursing with gengc") after drawing a second time. I will now try the solution mentioned by virgesmith

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Critten says these are structured exceptions. You can implement a custom handler for them if you really need to. I would start by reading the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling)

You can also translate these exceptions to C++ exceptions using a structured exception translator, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-160)

Bear in mind that quite likely you will have invoked undefined behaviour by triggering a structured exception, so do not assume you will be able to recover from it. Any handler/translator should be considered a diagnostic tool to help you fix these errors properly, as @RichardCritten points out

Comment: Translating these exceptions helps me now to catch them, but now I get the same exception as with the other solution "gengc 0x0EE2A9C8 leaving window 0x02137EA0 with recursion count of 2". Debugger breaks and I can't unset the checkmark on "break when this exception type is thrown". As all these exceptions only occur in debug version and the release runs without problems. Is there any way to tell the VS debugger just not to break when they occur?

Comment: @MTR These exceptions are symptoms of serious errors in the code.  You would be advised to fix them and not just to try and suppress the symptoms.

Comment: You are right on this point. But at the moment this is just not possible. The problem is in a big bunch of third-party code that uses OpenGL and as long as the release version does work, I don't get the time to solve it.